# parallel processing write dictionary to multiple csv files

Tags: python, dictionary, parallel-processing

I have a large dataframe that I would like to write to different files depending on the value in a particular column.

The first function takes a dictionary where the key is the file to write out to and the value is a numpy array which is a subset of the original dataframe.

```
def write_in_parallel(inputDict):
    for key,value in inputDict.items():
        df = pd.DataFrame(value)
        with open(baseDir + outDir + outputFileName + key + outputFileType, 'a') as oFile:
            data.to_csv(oFile, sep = '|', index = False, header = False)
        print("Finished writing month: " + outputFileName + key)
```

function 2 takes the column values for partitioning the dataframe and the dataframe itself, and returns the dataframe.

```
def make_slices(files, df):
    outlist = dict()
    for item in files:
        data = np.array(df[df.iloc[:,1] == item])
        outlist[item] = data
    return outlist
```

the final function uses multiprocessing to call `write_in_parallel` and iterates over the dictionary from `make_slices`, hopefully in parallel.

```
def make_dynamic_columns():
    perfPath = baseDir + rawDir
    perfFiles = glob.glob(perfPath + "/*" + inputFileType)
    perfFrame = pd.DataFrame()
    for file_ in perfFiles:
        df = pd.read_table(file_, delimiter = '|', header = None)

        df.fillna(missingDataChar,inplace=True)
        df.iloc[:,1] = df.iloc[:,1].astype(str)

        fileList = list(df.iloc[:, 1].astype('str').unique())

        with mp.Pool(processes=10) as pool:
            pool.map(write_in_parallel, make_slices(fileList, df))
```

the error I am getting is 'str object has no attribute items' which leads me to believe that pool.map and `write_in_parallel` is not receiving the dictionary. I am not sure how to solve this issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ssun/library/python/Python-3.5.2/build/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/ssun/library/python/Python-3.5.2/build/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "_FHLMC_LLP_dataprep.py", line 22, in write_in_parallel
    for key,value in dict.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_FHLMC_LLP_dataprep.py", line 59, in <module>
    make_dynamic_columns_freddie()
  File "_FHLMC_LLP_dataprep.py", line 55, in make_dynamic_columns_freddie
    pool.map(write_in_parallel, dictinput)
  File "/home/ssun/library/python/Python-3.5.2/build/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 260, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/home/ssun/library/python/Python-3.5.2/build/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace please

Comment: the traceback is added now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that make_slices returns a dictionary, not a list, and `pool.map()` does not like that. It just passes your dictionary keys to your workers, which means they are strings (try printing what you receive as `inputDict`). It is not dictionary but just keys.

```
def make_slices(files, df):
    outlist = []
    for item in files:
        data = df + item
        outlist.append({item: data})
    return outlist
```

Could you try something like this, so that you actually return a list? Members would then be dictionary items. (I had to modify your code to just create something in data to test).

This way you can receive a key and a related data item in your worker if that is what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue. I also had to recreate the dictionary in `write_in_parallel` via: 

`def write_in_parallel(dictinput):  
    dictinput = dict(item for item in dictinput)  
    for key,value in dictinput.items():` ...